# C# - One MAC Address, multiple source IP addresses

Tags: c#, dhcp

I am trying to write a Windows application which will generate traffic on an ethernet link from a PC.

I want to use webBrowser controls to continuously pull up web pages to generate the traffic.

In this case, i want each webBrowser control linked to a unique source IP address. Two questions:

1. Is it possible for one PC (i.e. one MAC address) to have multiple concurrent IP addresses assigned?
2. If the answer to question #1 is yes, is it easiest to use DHCP requests in the applications C# code to obtain the additional IP addresses, or is it easier to just configure static IP addresses?
3. How do i obtain the IP addresses obtained in step 2 in my C# code (just give me a general idea).

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Hello, item 1 doesn't belong to this forum, try in Superuser. Item 2 and 3, what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's absolutely possible for a single network adapter to have multiple IP addresses. I would however suggest configuring them manually (in Windows you can add additional IP addresses via the Advanced TCP/IP Settings in IPv4 properties of the network connection).

In terms of using those IP addresses, from code it's relatively easy, you can simply bind to a particular local IP address (if using the `TcpClient`, the `TcpClient(IPEndPoint localEndPoint)` constructor will allow you to do this).

However if you're using a web browser control it's perhaps rather more difficult, and it may not be possible via the publicly accessible interfaces on the control to bind it to a particular local address.

Providing you don't need any particularly advanced functionality, you may have more luck by creating your own simple HTTP requests and sending them over a suitably bound `TcpClient`.

**Edit:**

A quick search turned up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157593/381588) which may be of use - whilst it still doesn't allow you to use a graphical web browser control bound to a specific local address, it does enable you to use `HttpWebRequest`, which will allow you to handle send more advanced web requests (cookies, compression, redirects etc.).