# Programmatically choosing the Internet connection (WiFi, mobile broadband,...)

Tags: c#, mobile-broadband-api

I'm developing an application (.NET, C#) for a tablet to check the various networks available, e.g. WiFi or a mobile broadband connection like 4G or 3G. The application has to execute various tests, which basically involve connecting to a specified URL and logging the amount of data sent and returned plus the time involved.

The tablet is running Windows 8 (not 8.1), I'm developing on a Windows 7 PC using Visual Studio 2013. I've already managed to "discover" the active mobile broadband and WiFi connections.

If there are multiple available connections, e.g. both a 4G mobile broadband connection and a WiFi connection, the app should do the same tests on each. However, I still haven't found how I can specify which connection to use. Is this even possible? (How does the tablet pick which one to use?)

Comment: My idea was to disable all connections except the one I wanted to test, but that seems like a lot of hassle. I've tried looking for an API, but I cannot find anything, hence this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose one of many Internet connections for an application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [Choose one of many Internet connections for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application) basically answers the same problem.

You have to set the ServicePoint manually for your HttpWebRequest (which I assume you are using?). It's a bit of a hassle but totally doable. The idea behind using WebClient / HttpWebRequest is that you shouldn't have to worry about interfaces though :)

If you would like some code examples, just comment this answer with what's troubling you.

Comment: I am using HttpWebRequest, yes. Indeed, that question does look to be a relevant solution. I'll try that, thanks very much.

Comment: Took some work, but this seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe try search next time first.