# C# can i tell which internet connection to use

Tags: html

Is it possible in C# which internet connection to use?

This is for check:

```
Ping myPing = new Ping();
String host = "google.com";
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
int timeout = 1000;
PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
  // presumably online
}
```

Comment: Please read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details of how to format your post in future.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application