# Telling programs which Network connection to use

Tags: c#, networking, connection

We are connected most of the time with an VPN and a normal network.
Trough the VPN, we can't connect to some websites, some inhouse Databases etc., since these are blocked. I just had the crazy idea, I could create a small proxy program, which enforces the correct connection before starting the actual program.

I found the following example, which seems to make it possible to tell an own connection, which one to use:
[Choose one of many Internet connections for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application)

My question: Is it technically possible to force such a thing?

Manually it seems possible: If I disconnect the ethernet, connect via WLAN to the VPN, then connect back to the Ethernet, some programs seem to use the VPN first, since it was connected first.