# Select default network interface for Http requests in console app

Tags: c#, mono, network-programming, system.net, network-interface

I use mono to compile and run my C# console application. In that application i do several Http requests. Now i am in trouble with selecting proper network interface for app instance to send requests from.

Let's say i have `eth0` and `eth1` interfaces in my system. I need to force my application to use both of them in different instances. For example, when it starts first time, app chooses to use `eth0` and writes its number to `cache.txt`. If it starts again, it chooses second interface because `cache.txt` says that first interface is used by another instance.

Question: In C# application for mono runtime, how can enumerate and specify (at app startup) a network interface to be used for all TCP/Http/udp requests during this instance?

Comment: For inbound TcpListeners you can bind to an IP/Port and thus that would be either your `eth0` or `eth1` IP address. For outbound, you are looking at your TCP stack's `routing table`, i.e. `route -n`. If they both have access to the same subnets/gateway/etc... then the decision is based on the routing tables's metric

Comment: I am not sure what you're talking about. My primary question is what .Net/Mono classes or namespaces can help to select which interface is used by default in application for outgoing TCP/HTTP (by interfaces i actually mean IP address connected to my host and yes, available to use).

Comment: Other than that, you can control via `IPEndPoint`(s), look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application

Comment: Now i know that i need to explicitly bind on port and address before the request (which normally is not needed to connect), but how can i tweak my Http requests to bind on specific local endpoint by default?

Comment: If the http request class that you are using do not expose the socket's IPEndPoint (or similar), than you can't... Classes like `tcpClient` do expose it, but http ones...(?)

Comment: Code in answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5157593/3367446 looks like what i need. The question does it work as expected. I will test later but possibly it is not correct.

Comment: Cool, totally forgot about the callback... I'm interested now in knowing if it works correctly with the Mono framework on Linux... ;-)