# C# Test specific internet connection availability when we have multiple internet connections

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a computer with a few different internet connections. LAN, WLAN, WiFi or 3G. All of these are active and the machine can use any of them.

Now I want to tell my application to use one of the available connections. For example I want to tell my application to use only WiFi while other software might use something else.

And before telling application we select a internet and want to check that selected internet is working fine or not. So how we can check selected internet is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers here:
[Choose one of many Internet connections for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application)

However, is there any reason to specify network interface? If there are several network adapters, the *WebClient* or any other implementation will use interface with better metrics which you can retrieve by following code:

```
NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(adapter.Speed);
}
```

Adapter with better speed will be used by default, so you don't have to be afraid that 3G will be used instead of Wi-Fi or Wi-Fi instead of the Ethernet.