# How to connection multiples databases MySQL with C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am building an ASP.NET web API application, and I'm stuck in a problem... :/

I have **appsettings.json** to configure mysql connection:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CoinConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=root;port=3306;database=coin_db;Allow User Variables=True;",
    "UserConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=root;port=3306;database=user_db;Allow User Variables=True;"
  }
}
```

I have **Startup.cs** to execute the service to connect mysql:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<AppDb>(_ => new AppDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:CoinConnection"]));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have **AppDb.cs** to receive a string and connect in database **coin_db** in mysql:

```
using System;
using MySqlConnector;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class AppDb : IDisposable
    {
        public MySqlConnection Connection { get; }

        public AppDb(string connectionString)
        {
            Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public void Dispose() => Connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**I don't know how I can do to connect the second database (user_db)...** I've tried everything and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can simply have two classes, each connecting to a different database. I would definitely dispose of the connection immediately after each use instead of when the class is disposed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a different AppDb implementation for each db?
Then you can access them via dependency injection in your routes.

```
public class UserDb : AppDb 
{
   public UserDb(string connectionString) 
   : base(connectionString)
   {}
   // ...
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<AppDb>(_ => new AppDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:CoinConnection"])); // TODO: use CoinDb class and make AppDb class abstract
    services.AddTransient<UserDb>(_ => new UserDb(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:UserConnection"]));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a second connection, if it is the same server.

Simply add the database name before the table name

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM coin_db.table1 a INNER JOIN user_db.tabl2 b ON a.id P= b.id
```

Mysql can identify so, whichtable you mean.

two connection is possible see here [Choose one of many Internet connections for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547032/choose-one-of-many-internet-connections-for-an-application)